# Visual Studio Resharper with TypeScript and node_modules

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, resharper

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. When I try to use Resharper to Refactor my TypeScript code, Resharper tries to refactor code in every folder, including `node_modules`. Obviously, I do not want Resharper to touch `node_modules` because those are 3rd party libraries (not my code) and it would probably take 6 hours to try to go through all of those folders I have in `node_modules`. How do I get Resharper to ignore `node_modules` in all instances, especially in the Refactor process?

I have already tried the following:

- Resharper... Options... Search & Navigation... Elements to skip... Add node_modules
- Resharper... Options... Code Inspection... Settings... Elements to skip... Add node_modules

I also tried changing the node_modules folder to Hidden in its Windows Folder Properties, but Resharper still gets in there for that Refactor process.

What else do I need to do to get Resharper to ignore `node_modules`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

`Resharper... Options... Code Editing... Third-Party Code... Library code... Add node_modules`

Problem solved!

Comment: This gives "Some selected folders are not part of solution and were not added". (https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000087050-Resharper-exclude-node-modules-from-Refactor)

Comment: Use a file mask: node_modules\**